# Sticky corn starch croquette

Tags: gluten-free, cornstarch

I'm having a coeliac over for dinner and I've made croquettes from corn starch. I have a recipe with 100gr corn starch and 700ml liquid. That works fine. But when forming the croquette, the batter will stick to my hands... a lot.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Nice edit Erik... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the water in your skin more so than anything else that makes it stick to your hands; generally the most effective way to prevent any kind of water-based dough or batter from sticking to your hands is by greasing them.  Some of the fat might get into the dough, but not really enough to make a difference.

Any kind of fat will do. Vegetable oil is the economical choice but margarine or shortening will coat the hands much more effectively.

If you've got gloves then it's even easier, just spray them generously with cooking spray before you put them on and start to work the dough.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally suggest covering your hands in a bit of flour, but that sort of defeats the purpose of cooking gluten-free. Maybe you can get the same effect by covering your hands with a bit of corn starch.

Comment: If you're going to then be dipping it in an egg wash, and then breadcrumbs (well, maybe not *bread* crumbs) before frying, I'd go with this method over using oil or grease.  The powder will bind to any free moisture in your hands.  If you're using a disher to size the croquettes, you could also scoop and then drop it in cornstarch to get extra starch on the outside.